# python requests post aplicação laravel

Tags: python, laravel, python-requests

Estou enviando dados via post para uma aplicação web feita em laravel com o `CSRF` ativo.

O formulário é esse:

Obs: editei o `_token`.

```html
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/posicoes">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="abcdef">    <div>
    <span>MD5</span>
        <input type="text" id="md5" name="md5" maxlength="50" size="50">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="file" id="jsonFile" name="jsonFile">
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Meu código para envio é esse:

```
def enviar(self, dados, path_post):
    md5 = dados['md5']
    path_arquivo = dados['arquivo']

    formulario = {}
    formulario['md5'] = md5

    url = 'http://' + self.host + path_post

    session = requests.session()
    form = session.get(url)
    csrf_token = re.findall(r'<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="(.*)"', form.text)[0]
    cookies = session.cookies
    
    formulario['_token'] = csrf_token
    
    files = {'jsonFile':('dados_gps.json', open(path_arquivo, 'rb'))}
    
    response = session.post(url, files=files, data=formulario, cookies=cookies)

    
    return response
```

mas a resposta é sempre o erro `405`.

Comment: Erro 405 é método não permitido. já tentou `session.get`?

Comment: Não porque preciso enviar dados ao servidor

Comment: post seria o correto, mas depende da implementação no servidor. De novo, 405 é método não aceito. Ou seja, o endpoint não aceita POST.

Comment: Quando eu faço manualmente ou seja colo o md5 no campo e seleciono o arquivo o post funciona corretamente. Os dados são salvos na aplicação normalmente. Isso não é prova que esta funcionando corretamente?

Comment: O caminho que o desenvolvedor da aplicação web me passou estava errado. O post estava em /posicoes e não em /posicoes/create. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Não entendi como manualmente funcionava, mas o caminho que te passaram estava errado... Mesmo assim, que bom que funcionou.